# Retrieve data from firebase and Unique key

Tags: javascript, node.js, firebase, express

I would retrieve data from a firebase DB. here's the schema of my database

```
datatable-18f93
  -L5pD-jh_Xpqq6bq2eDS
    text: "HELEO"
  -L5pDT-IpB4BsFMiABv_
    text: "HELEO"
  -L5pPwXnuTsSXN9pXpJ5
    text: "popopo"
```

I have created a get route to get data

```
router
  .route("/")
  .get(function (req, res, err) {
    console.log("test", req.body)

    // Get a database reference to our posts
    var db = admin.database();
    var ref = db.ref("/");

    // Attach an asynchronous callback to read the data at our posts reference
    ref.on("value", function (snapshot) {
      console.log(snapshot.val())
      res.send(snapshot.val());

    }, function (errorObject) {
      console.log("The read failed: " + errorObject.code);
    });
  });
```

This route is printing also the unique key

```
{ '-L5pD-jh_Xpqq6bq2eDS': { text: 'HELEO' },
  '-L5pDT-IpB4BsFMiABv_': { text: 'HELEO' },
  '-L5pPwXnuTsSXN9pXpJ5': { text: 'popopo' } }
```

What I want is only the objects without id. how can I get that ?
Here's an example

```
{ text: 'HELEO' },
{ text: 'HELEO' },
{ text: 'popopo' }
```

Comment: You should be using once() instead of on() for one-time requests.  Right now, you are setting up a listener that's going to be called repeatedly with every single change in your database.  That's bad.

Comment: Thanks but I would make a realtime to do list so I think I should use on()

Comment: Don't use on().  That doesn't make the request any faster than once(). Please take some time understand the difference between on() and once().  You will see that once() makes more sense for a one-time request that must terminate at the end.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to loop through snapshot and push the obj element into new array

```
ref.once("value", function (snapshot) {
    var list = [];
    snapshot.forEach(function(elem) {
        list.push(elem.val());
    });
    res.send(list);
}, function (errorObject) {
  console.log("The read failed: " + errorObject.code);
});
```

Comment: You should be using once() instead of on().  See my comment on the question.

Comment: I get an error : `can't set header after they are sent` on line when I post in database, the error is in the line : `res.send(list)`

Comment: Do you using on or once?